# Can I force install of a package delete from yum repo?

Tags: yum

I have some chef recipes referencing the package `php53u`. It seems that at the time the recipes were written, the package was available in ius repo, but now it seems that package `php` installs version `5.3.3` and there is no `php53u` package at all. Can I force yum to use old version of repository so that the package can be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I force yum to use old version of repository so that the package can be found?

No you just kind of have to go based on what the repo has available. If they got rid of that package then that's all she wrote. You may try using google to find an IUS mirror repo that is still available but hasn't been synced in a while. That's kind of laborious but it may work.

> but now it seems that package php installs version 5.3.3 and there is no php53u package at all.

I don't have much experience with IUS so I don't know what's different about this build than the standard RHEL build, but there's a [php55u](http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/repoview/php55u.html) package currently available for EL6 and a [php54](http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/x86_64/repoview/letter_p.group.html) for EL5. Are either of those acceptable for your purposes?

Comment: Nah my main purpose was not to edit chef repos, guess I'll have to do it

Answer (score 0):

You have to put back the old repository in your /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory, or if present but disable , you can enable it by doing a `yum --enablerepo=nameoftherepo`

If you want to downgrade a package you can use the command `yum downgrade packageName`

I'm not sure if this helps you

Cheers.

Comment: fwiw if they're saying they can't find a package in the repo at all, `yum downgrade` isn't going to be able to find a version to downgrade to. `php53` and `php` are considered different packages for instance.

Comment: yes i have misunderstood what Fluffy was saying, but thanks for the reminder.